# extracting IP values

Tags: python, scripting

Can someone help be? I am new on this site and new to python.
I have to write a script to take the last two oct of an IP and do some calc to match them with the port number.
I have been banging my head against the wall trying really hard to get the last two values of an IP. 
Any help would be great. This is my code:

```
import sys
import re

    t= open('fileD.txt','r')
    t = t.readline()
    s = t.split(";")
    holder = []
    wordlist = {}
    print s

    for c in s:
        wordlist[c.split()[0]] = c.split()
        print c
        with open('filex.txt','w') as x:
            x = x.write(c)

    x = open('filek.txt','w')
    with open ('filex.txt', 'r') as f:
        column = 0
        for line in f:
            if not re.match('@', line):
                line = line.strip()
                sline = line.split()
                x.write(sline[column] + '\n')
    x.close()
    sys.exit(0)
```

This is the content of `fileD.txt`:

```
99413 ;199.189.17.13 9999
99413 ;199.189.17.13 9999
99414 ;199.189.17.14 9999
99414 ;199.189.17.14 9999
99414 ;199.189.17.14 9999
99415 ;199.189.17.15 9999
99415 ;199.189.17.15 9999
99415 ;199.189.17.15 9999
```

So, I need to take the `.17` and the `.10` and put them into a calculation to produce `99415`, which is a port.

Comment: (A textbook example on how NOT to compose question titles.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a list comprehension:

```
with open('fileD.txt') as f:
    last_two_nums = [line.split()[1][-5:].split('.') for line in f] # [['17', '13'], ['17', '13'], ...]
```

**Or**

```
with open('fileD.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        last_two_nums = line.split()[1][-5:].split('.') # gives for ex: ['17', '13']
        # do what you've got to do here
```

You could access them via `last_two_nums[0]` or `last_two_nums[1]`
Make sure to convert them from strings to numbers before any calculations
with `int()` or `float()`

Answer (score 0):

You can make it like:

```
file = open("fileD.txt","r")

for line in file: # for example, first line
    ipparts = line.split()[1][1:].split(".") # list as ["199","189","17","13"]
    thirdgroup = ipparts[2] # "17"
    forthgroup = ipparts[3] # "13"
    # make here what you want with those values.

file.close()
```